# How can I prove that this sequence of integers exists?

Tags: general-topology

So the question I'm currently having trouble with is this one. Suppose $0\le\alpha\lt1$. Prove that the the following sequence of integers $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $\ldots$(0$\le$$a_n$$\le$9) exists, such that for any natural number N $\in$$\Bbb{N}$:$$|\alpha-\sum_{n=1}^Na_n10^{-n}|<10^{-N}$$
For the first step, I tried to get rid of all | | signs, then tried to multiply 10 to all sides, struggling to prove that $a_1$ should exist somewhere from 1 to 9 due to the modified inequality. However, I couldn't obtain a valid inequality and so my point is stuck. I would appreciate any advice on this question. Thanks.
(edit)
For the next try, I also tried induction on N, and it seems to be the right way, but I'm finding trouble in inducing the case N = k+1 from the case N = k.

Comment: Hint: think of the (possibly infinite) decimal expansion.

Comment: @Jason: Presumably this is about proving that the decimal expansion exists. In other words, $\alpha$ is an equivalence class of rational Cauchy sequences. Decimals don't exist yet. The tag is [tag:general-topology], and this is a natural step in studying the topological completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ w.r.t. the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll work it in detail:

Let $\alpha \in [0,1[$

Let $a_{n (n\ge 1)} $ the $n^{th}$ decimal representation of $\alpha $.

Let $$B_{N (N\ge 1)}= \sum_{n=1}^{N} {a _n 10^{-n}} $$
From the definition of $a_n: B_N $ converges to $\alpha $.
$$ \alpha - B_N = \lim_{p \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{p}{a _n 10^{-n}}- \sum_{n=1}^{N} {a _n 10^{-n}}}\\
=\lim_{p \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=N+1}^{p}{a _n 10^{-n}}}  $$
Now we have: $\forall n \in \mathbb {N}: \quad0\le a_n \le9$
$$\Rightarrow 0 \le  \lim_{p \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=N+1}^{p}{a _n 10^{-n}}} \le \lim_{p \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=N+1}^{p}{9 .{10}^{-n}}}$$.
And :
$$\lim_{p \to +\infty}{\sum_{n=N+1}^{p}{9 .{10}^{-n}}} 
= \lim_{p \to +\infty}{9.\frac {{10}^{-N-1}-{10}^{-p}}{1-\frac {1}{10}}}= 9.\frac {{10}^{-N-1}}{\frac {9}{10}}= {10}^{-N}$$
And now we must admit that: $\forall p \in \mathbb{N},\exists n > p  :\quad a_n <9$.

So we finally can say that: $0 <\alpha - B_N <{10}^{-N} \Rightarrow \vert \alpha-B_N\vert <{10}^{-N}$.

Now I'll let you the task to find a way to generalize from the $\alpha = 0.5$ case that there exists another sequence in which only the weak inequality holds
(To make it easier, in that case, $\alpha$ must have a finite decimal represenation)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add the equality sign in your inequality because it does hold only if $\forall n \in \mathbb {N}$ the $n^{th}$ digit of the decimal reprisentation  of $\alpha$ **Is Equal to** $a_{n}$.

So the Original inequality should become:
$$\vert {\alpha - \sum_{n=1}^{N} {a_n {10}^{-n}}}\vert\le {10}^{-N}$$
And now: You just asked about the proof of the existence of such sequence, a short and easy way is to construct such sequence (The one mentionned abose is sufficient, but I am adding another exemple).

Let $a_1 = 4 \quad a_{n (n>1)}=9 $ 
And let $\alpha = 0.5$

Clearly $$\forall N \in \mathbb{N} :\alpha > \sum_{n=1}^{N} {a_n {10}^{-n}}$$
And 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} {a_n {10}^{-n}}
= \frac4 {10} + 9\sum_{n=2}^{N} { {10}^{-n}}\\
= \frac4 {10} + 9\frac {{10}^{-2}-{10}^{-N-1}}{1-{10}^{-1}}\\
=\frac4 {10} + 9\frac{{10}^{-2}-{10}^{-N-1}}{\frac {9}{10}}\\
=\frac4 {10} + \frac 1{10}- {10}^{-N}\\
= \alpha - {10}^{-N}
$$
Now 
$$\vert {\alpha - \sum_{n=1}^{N} {a_n {10}^{-n}}}\vert \le 
{10}^{-N}\\
\Leftrightarrow \vert {10}^{-N} \vert\le {10}^{-N}\quad\text{(Which is True)}$$

Comment: Hi Rami. Thank you for replying, but there are few things in your proof that i can't understand. I thought we had to prove the inequality for all possible $\alpha$, but your proof only proves the case when it's 0.5. So are you saying that any $\alpha$ can be proved the same way?